# delphi pointer address

Tags: delphi, pointers, pointer-address

In Delphi:

**How do I get the address (0x2384293) a pointer points to?**

```
var iValue := Integer;
    iptrValue := PInteger;

implementation

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  iptrValue := @iValue;
  iValue := 32342;
  //Should return the same value:
  Edit1.Text := GetAddressOf(iptrValue);
  Edit2.Text := GetAddressOf(iValue);
```

So what is GetAddress in reality :)

Comment: GetAddressOf does not exist. it was pseudocode as stated in "in reality" :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To *get* the address of something, use the `@` operator or the `Addr` function. You've already demonstrated correct use of that. You got the address of `iValue` and stored it in `iptrValue`.

To *display* an address, you can use the `Format` function to convert a pointer value into a string. Use the `%p` format string:

```
Edit1.Text := Format('%p -> %p -> %d', [@iptrValue, iptrValue, iptrValue^]);
```

That will display the address of the `iptrValue` variable, then the address *stored in* that variable, and then the *value* stored at that address.

The `iptrValue` variable declaration reserves some bytes in memory and associates a name with them. Suppose the address of the first byte is `$00002468`:

```
       iptrValue
       +----------+
$2468: |          |
       +----------+
```

The `iValue` declaration reserves another piece of memory, and it will probably be adjacent to the previous declaration's memory. Since `iptrValue` is four bytes wide, the address of `iValue` would be `$0000246C`:

```
       iValue
       +----------+
$246c: |          |
       +----------+
```

The boxes I've drawn are empty for now because we haven't discussed what values those variables hold. We've only discussed the variables' addresses. Now to the executable code: You write `@iValue` and store the result in `iptrValue`, so you get this:

```
       iptrValue
       +----------+    +----------+
$2468: |    $246c |--->|          |
       +----------+    +----------+
       iValue
       +----------+
$246c: |          |
       +----------+


Next, you assign 32342 to `iValue`, so your memory looks like this:


       iptrValue
       +----------+    +----------+
$2468: |    $246c |--->|    32342 |
       +----------+    +----------+
       iValue
       +----------+
$246c: |    32342 |
       +----------+
```

Finally, when you display the results of the `Format` function from above, you would see this value:

```
00002468 -> 0000246C -> 32342
```

Comment: Hi @Rob, I think your diagram is misleading. It gives the reader a feeling that the memory address the pointer points to is not the box at $246c. Imo, it's better to draw it like this: https://i.imgur.com/qXSWa3y.png

Answer (score 5):

Just cast it to an integer  :)

IIRC, there's also a string format specifier (%x? %p?) that will automagically format it as an 8-character hex string.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my own example of address function:

```
function GetAddressOf( var X ) : String;
Begin
  Result := IntToHex( Integer( Pointer( @X ) ), 8 );
end;
```

Example of using 2 variable's same data:

```
type
  TMyProcedure = procedure;

procedure Proc1;
begin
  ShowMessage( 'Hello World' );
end;

var
  P : PPointer;
  Proc2 : TMyProcedure;
begin
  P := @@Proc2; //Storing address of pointer to variable
  P^ := @Proc1; //Setting address to new data of our stored variable
  Proc2; //Will execute code of procedure 'Proc1'
end;
```

Comment: That's not always correct due to the size differences between pointer and integer

Answer (score 3):

GetAddressOf() will return the address of the variable.

```
GetAddressOf(iptrValue) - the address of the iptrValue
GetAddressOf(iValue) - the address of iValue
```

What you want is the value of the pointer. To do so cast the pointer to an unsigned integer type (Longword if I remember it right). Then you can convert that integer into a string.

Answer (score 2):

It actually is a ULong you need:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var iValue : Integer;
    iAdrValue : ULong;
    iptrValue : PInteger;
begin
  iValue := 32342;
  iAdrValue := ULong(@iValue);
  iptrValue := @iValue;

  //Should return the same value:
  Edit1.Text := IntToStr(iAdrValue);
  Edit2.Text := IntToStr(ULong(iptrValue)); 
  Edit3.Text := IntToStr((iptrValue^); // Returns 32342
end;
```

I did not find the GetAddressOf function in Delphi 2006. It seems to be a VB function?